# Windows 10 Store icons are broken?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons, start-menu

For some reason all my Store apps seem to have broken icons. I've reinstalled them multiple times and even run `sfc /scannow` just in case. Nothing has changed.

Here's what it looks like.

In the Start menu, they look fine:

[image: Start Menu]

However, if you launch any of them, the icons mess up like in the taskbar here:

[image: Calculator and Camera in the taskbar]

It looks like any transparency within the image is replaced with black and any transparency outside the main image is replaced with white. Antialiasing also seems to be nonexistent.

Also, if you search for one in the Start Menu, it appears as a page icon:

[image]

I should add that all the apps work fine and the icons within the apps themselves look fine.

Also, right clicking on a taskbar icon usually shows the name of the program and it's icon and a few options like so:

[image: Okay taskbar > rclick]

But in the case of my broken Store apps, the icon isn't there at all:

[image: Broken taskbar > rclick]

Has anyone else encountered this before? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Reinstalling Windows is an option but I'd rather not because it's a bit tedious to have to set everything up again.

Comment: You have ran DISM, SFC isn't really applicable to Windows 8+, but my recommendation would be to Refresh your installation.  Yes; This basically means your reinstalling Windows.  Something is obviously corrupt though.  You might consider waiting for 1709 which might solve the problem when it's installed

Comment: Check the images in Assets folder of that UWP app in ProgramFiles\WindowsApps directory.

Comment: @Biswa The images in the folders seem fine.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved I had to uncheck "Always show icons, never thumbnails" in folder option --> View Tab and restart computer.